# Problema con insertar y suprimir de lista bidireccional en C

Tags: c, lista, insert, codeblocks

Comparto las funciones *insertar* y *suprimir* de una *lista bidireccional*.

Usando el método que he aplicado para definirla, no inserta correctamente y cuelga los programas que use con ellas.

```
void insertar(listabi *L,datos elem){
    nodo *p=(nodo*)malloc(sizeof(nodo));
    (*L).cursor->VIPD=elem;
    if((*L).acceso==NULL){
        (*L).acceso=p;
        (*p).ps=(*L).cursor;
        (*p).pa=NULL;
        (*L).cursor=p;
        (*L).cursoraux=p;
    }
    else{
       if((*L).acceso==(*L).cursor){
         (*L).acceso=p;
         (*p).ps=(*L).cursor;
         (*L).cursor->pa=p;
         (*p).pa=NULL;
         (*L).cursor=p;

       }
        else{
            if((*L).cursor!=NULL){
            (*p).ps=(*L).cursor;
            (*p).pa=(*L).cursoraux;
            (*L).cursor->pa=p;
            (*L).cursor=p;
            (*L).cursoraux=p;
            }
            else{
            (*p).ps=(*L).cursor;
            (*p).pa=(*L).cursoraux;
            (*L).cursoraux->ps=p;
            (*L).cursor=p;
            (*L).cursoraux=p;
            }
        }
    }
}

void suprimir(listabi *L){
    if((*L).acceso==(*L).cursor){
        (*L).acceso=((*L).cursor)->ps;
        free((*L).cursor);
        (*L).cursor=(*L).acceso;
        (*L).cursoraux=(*L).cursor;
    }
    else{
        if((*L).cursor!=NULL){
            (*L).cursoraux->ps=(*L).cursor->ps;
            free((*L).cursor);
            (*L).cursor=(*L).cursoraux->ps;
            (*L).cursor->pa=(*L).cursoraux;
        }
        else{
            (*L).cursoraux->ps=NULL;
            free((*L).cursor);
            (*L).cursor=(*L).cursoraux;
        }
    }
}
```

En estas funciones, no es necesario que se muestre el código completo para revisar si están correctas, ya que funcionan indiferente del programa que se está creando.

Definición de *nodo* y *listabi*:

```
typedef struct{
    varados VIPD;
    struct nodo *ps;
    struct nodo *pa; 
}nodo;

typedef struct{
    nodo *acceso;
    nodo *cursor;
    nodo *cursoraux;  }listabi;
```

Definicion de **tda.h**

```
typedef struct {
    char apellido[30];
    char nombre[30]; 
}datos;

void cargar_apellido(datos *v,char a[]) {
    strcpy((*v).apellido,a); }

void cargar_nombre(datos *v,char n[]) {
    strcpy((*v).nombre,n); }

char* ver_apellido(datos v) {
    char *aux;
    aux=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    if(aux==NULL)
        exit(1);
    else
    {
        strcpy(aux,v.apellido);
        return aux;
    }
}
char* ver_nombre(datos v) {
    char *aux1;
    aux1=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    if(aux1==NULL)
        exit(1);
    else
    {
        strcpy(aux1,v.nombre);
        return aux1;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuáles son tus datos de entrada? ¿Cuáles son tus datos de salida? ¿Qué salida esperabas encontrar? ¿Qué error(es) han sucedido? ¿Cuál es la definición de `listabi`? ¿Cuál es la definición de `nodo`?

Comment: `L->` es siempre mejor de `(*L).`.

Comment: Aclararte que el uso de `(*L).` es totalmente válido, pero escribir `L->` es totalmente equivalente y es más claro y fácil de leer. De ahí la recomendación de @n.'pronouns'm.

Comment: Mis datos de entrada, son datos para un tda, por ejemplo algun nombre y apellido de persona. El tda luego se inserta a la lista. Ahi es donde da error, no se copia a lista y cuelga el progama. La definicion de lista la agrego en la edicion de la entrada. @PaperBirdMaster

Comment: lo de L-> es cuestion del compilador que lo pide asi cuando referencia a un puntero del nodo @n.'pronouns'm.

Comment: ¿Qué entiendes por lista bidireccional? ¿Qué cometido tienen los miembros `acceso`, `cursor` y `cursoraux` del tip `listabi`?

Comment: ¿El programa compila? ¿Te aparece algún error de compilación o ejecución? ¿Cuál es el problema?

Comment: @ArtEze compila sin detectar ningun error. Pero al ejecutarse se cuelga. Me aparecen warnings, pero esos no deberian realmente afectar al programa.

Comment: @MarcosPerez Me aparece que falta `varados` y `datos`

Comment: @ArtEze Si necesitas, los agrego en otra edicion

Comment: @MarcosPerez Sí, eso estaría bien.

Comment: @ArtEze recorda definir la lista en un header.h y el tda en otro header.h

Comment: Gracias por ayudarme a editar la publicacion. Se me complica bastante hacerlo. @ArtEze

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110144/discussion-between-arteze-and-marcos-perez).